# SidebySideConfiguration error while launching an EXE

Tags: visual-studio, side-by-side

I'm encountering Side-by-Side configuration error when launching an EXE with arguments in CommandPrompt. This EXE is a third party EXE and it's ensured to be a working one.

But it does not work in my system - Am I missing anything? I used sxstrace in the eventlog to view the details - below is what I got. I'm not able to interpret.

I've VS 2012 installed in my machine already - also VC++2012/2010/2008 redistributable packages additionally.

> ================= Begin Activation Context Generation. Input Parameter:   Flags = 0   ProcessorArchitecture = x86     CultureFallBacks =
>   en-US;en  ManifestPath = C:\Users\20121011_PR2_1\Desktop\HotPlugUnplug
>   Stress\SourceCode\Soft_BIOS\bin\DvmuInstaller\Installer.exe
>     AssemblyDirectory = C:\Users\20121011_PR2_1\Desktop\HotPlugUnplug
>   Stress\SourceCode\Soft_BIOS\bin\DvmuInstaller\    Application Config
>   File = 
>   ----------------- INFO: Parsing Manifest File C:\Users\20121011_PR2_1\Desktop\HotPlugUnplug
>   Stress\SourceCode\Soft_BIOS\bin\DvmuInstaller\Installer.exe.  INFO:
>   Manifest Definition Identity is (null).   INFO: Reference:
>   Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8"
>     INFO: Reference:
>   Microsoft.VC90.DebugMFC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8"
>   INFO: Resolving reference
>   Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8".
>     INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.        INFO:
>   Resolving reference for culture Neutral.          INFO: Applying Binding
>   Policy.
>                 INFO: No publisher policy found.
>                 INFO: No binding policy redirect found.             INFO: Begin assembly probing.
>                 INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
>                 INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT\9.0.21022.8__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT.DLL.
>                 INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Users\20121011_PR2_1\Desktop\HotPlugUnplug
>   Stress\SourceCode\Soft_BIOS\bin\DvmuInstaller\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT.DLL.
>                 INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Users\20121011_PR2_1\Desktop\HotPlugUnplug
>   Stress\SourceCode\Soft_BIOS\bin\DvmuInstaller\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT.MANIFEST.
>                 INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Users\20121011_PR2_1\Desktop\HotPlugUnplug
>   Stress\SourceCode\Soft_BIOS\bin\DvmuInstaller\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT.DLL.
>                 INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Users\20121011_PR2_1\Desktop\HotPlugUnplug
>   Stress\SourceCode\Soft_BIOS\bin\DvmuInstaller\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT.MANIFEST.
>                 INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.            INFO: End assembly probing.     ERROR: Cannot resolve reference
>   **Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8".**
>   ERROR: Activation Context generation failed. End Activation Context
>   Generation.

Answer (score 5):

The executable is looking for the Debug version of the VC 9.0 Common Run Time (Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT). This library is not a part of the redistributable package for the Common Runtime.  I forget why Microsoft has this stipulation. Maybe it's a security or a legal issue.

You have three options:

1. Ask the person who gave you the executable to rebuild the executable in release mode so that the executable links against the release version of the CRT. That's the version you have installed from the redistributable package.
2. Ask the person who gave you the executable to send the DebugCRT versions of the CRT. Look in the Visual Studio install location for the VC folder.  Then look for `redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86`.
3. Install Visual Studio/Visual Studio express with C++.  This will install the debug version of the CRT on your machine.

Comment: I rebuild the executable in release mode and it solved the problem :-)